# ExtJS: How to access Ajax request's value from any other proxy?

Tags: javascript, ms-access, extjs, proxy

I'm getting some specific data from a web-service and need to transfer this data to another web-service's `extraParams`. How can I achieve to it?

I've created a `singleton` class which handles information and after fetching those data; another store `proxy` will use those data.

This is singleton class;

```
Ext.define('MyApp.MyInfo', {
    requires: [] ,

    singleton: true,

    getMyId: function () {
        var me = this;

        var request = Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: myUrl() + '/info', //Here is web-service url

            success: function(response, opts) {
                var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                var myId = obj.data[0].id; // Successfully gets required ID

                console.log(myId); // Successfully prints ID value
                // callback(userGid); //Not sure if callback method will handle ID value to fetch on any other class..            
            },

            failure: function(response, opts) {
                console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

and here is other `proxy` which needs `myId` value from `Ajax.request` above;

```
stores: {
        myFooStore: {
            model: 'MyApp.Model',
            autoLoad: true,
            session: true,
            proxy: {
                url: myUrl() + '/the/other/service', 
                type: 'ajax',
                extraParams: {                   
                    id: // HERE! I need to get myId value on here. And couldn't get it.
                },
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'data'
                }
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `store` auto load you need to call [`store.load()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#method-load) method to load your particular store. And you can pass your params using [`store.getProxy()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#method-getProxy) like below example:

```
//you can set using get proxy
store.getProxy().setExtraParams({
    id: id
});
store.load()

//or you can direcly pass inside of store.load method like this
store.load({
    params: {
        id: 'value' //whatever your extraparms you can pass like this
    }
});
```

In this [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2g6f), I have created a demo based on your requirement.

Code snippet:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.define('MyInfo', {

            alternateClassName: "myinfo",

            singleton: true,

            getMyId: function (callback) {
                var me = this;

                Ext.Ajax.request({

                    url: 'id.json', //Here is web-service url

                    success: function (response, opts) {
                        var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText),
                            myId = obj.data[0].id; // Successfully gets required ID

                        console.log(myId); // Successfully prints ID value

                        callback(myId);
                    },
                    failure: function (response, opts) {
                        callback('');
                        console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        Ext.define('MyViewController', {
            extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
            alias: 'controller.myview',

            onLoadButtonTap: function () {
                var view = this.getView(),
                    myFooStore = this.getViewModel().getStore('myFooStore');
                view.mask('Please wait..');
                myinfo.getMyId(function (id) {
                    view.unmask();
                    if (id) {
                        myFooStore.getProxy().setExtraParams({
                            id: id
                        });
                        myFooStore.load();
                        /*
                        You can also do like this

                        myFooStore.load({
                            url:'',//If you want to change url dynamically
                            params:{
                                id:'value'//whatever your extraparms you can pass like this
                            }
                        });

                        */
                    }
                });

            }
        });

        Ext.define("ViewportViewModel", {
            extend: "Ext.app.ViewModel",

            alias: 'viewmodel.myvm',

            stores: {
                myFooStore: {

                    fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],

                    proxy: {
                        type: 'ajax',

                        url: 'data1.json',

                        reader: {
                            type: 'json',
                            rootProperty: ''
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        //creating panel with GRID and FORM
        Ext.create({

            xtype: 'panel',

            controller: 'myview',

            title: 'Demo with singletone class',

            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

            viewModel: {
                type: 'myvm'
            },

            layout: 'vbox',

            items: [{
                xtype: 'grid',

                flex: 1,

                width: '100%',

                bind: '{myFooStore}',

                columns: [{
                    text: 'Name',
                    dataIndex: 'name'
                }, {
                    text: 'Email',
                    dataIndex: 'email',
                    flex: 1
                }, {
                    text: 'Phone',
                    dataIndex: 'phone'
                }]
            }],

            tbar: [{
                text: 'Load Data',
                handler: 'onLoadButtonTap'
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'll have another question; Already I can get myId value from `MyInfo`class with `var myId = obj.data[0].id;` So can I fetch to this data on second `store` with something like; `extraParams: {id: MyApp.MyInfo. getMyId(). myId},`. This way dynamically I'll load ID based store and I'll achieve to required data with calling `variable` itself?

Comment: Or something like; extraParams: `{id: MyApp.MyInfo. getMyId().success(myId)}`? The `callback(myId);` method will be working on `MyInfo` singleton class.

Comment: If you are creating dynamic store then it's ok but in case of if you already defined your stored in any class or view-model so whenever  you set `extraParams: {id: MyApp.MyInfo. getMyId(). myId}`  if value is find then it's work otherwise not.

Comment: For this you can try `extraParams: {id: MyApp.MyInfo. getMyId().success(myId)}` may be this will work not sure I need to check once.

Comment: It keeps fail; As you'll notice on my snippet I've declared `MyInfo` class, then has `getMyId` function. It's includes `request` variable to create ajax request and then `myId` variable stays in `success` function. So I've tried this; `MyApp.MyInfo.getMyId().request.success(myId)` and returns as `request property undefined`. Also tried this; `MyApp.MyInfo.getMyId().success(myId)` then says `success property undefined`... Couldn't get myId yet.

Comment: and dear @N.Jadhav I've implemented your sample; I'm using some `panel` stuff so within ViewController defined `listeners: {beforerender: myFunc}`. Successfully executes the function but gives error through MyInfo class: `Uncaught ReferenceError: callback is not defined`.  Should I change anything on `success` method of ajax request?

Comment: But of course the first approach I mentioned will be much easier to implement my achieve to project.

Comment: The `extraParams: {id:}` will be always different. Means depends on request what value comes from there. so I think you should always pass the value after getting value of id from that request.

Comment: Dear @N.Jadhav I had a typo error therefore got callback error. Now all done. Thanks a lot.